# Excel Expert Needed - How can I get Excel to dynamically update one cell based on the input of a number of different cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wish there is an Excel Expert out there who can solve this for me.

I'm making a little spreadsheet tacker for migrating servers.

I want excel to dynamically change a particular cell value based on input from a number of different cells. For example, lets say cell **"C1"** is the cell that should **change dynamically** and cells **"D1, E1 and F1"** are the cells where I input something. These three input cells all have a 'drop down' list of three options each to select from. The drop down options are **"In Progress, Problem, Done"**.

I want excel to update cell **"C1"** **(the dynamically changing cell)** if I select **"Done"** from the input selection in cell **"D1"**. The end result in **"C1"** should now display **"Done"**. Likewise, if I select **"Problem"** in cell **"D1"** from the selection list, then the end result in **"C1"** should now display **"Problem"** instead.

Now it gets a little more complex and unsure if Excel can do this for me, I will explain further. If cell **"D1"** is selected as **"Done"** and cell **"E1"** is selected as **"Problem"**, then I want Excel to update cell **"C1"** with **"Problem"** and ignore what was previously displayed in cell **"C1"**, which was **"Done"**. Basically, if any of my input cells are selected with **"Problem"** then I want my cell **"C1"** **(dynamically changing cell)** to always say **"Problem"**, even if any of the other input cells are showing as **"Done"**.

If there is anybody out there who can help by providing a formula that can achieve the above then it will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula in Cell C1:

```
=IF(OR(D1="Problem";D1="Problem";F1="Problem");"Problem";IF(OR(D1="In Progress";E1="In Progress";F1="In Progress");"In Progress";"Done"))
```

This should solve your problem. Basically, what is being considered here is that if any cell has a problem, then C1 will show **Problem**, if there's two cells with **Done** and another one with value **In Progress**, then this will show as **In Progress**. And last but not least, if all cells are **Done**, then C1 will be equal **Done**.

Comment: Many thanks Niko - I will try it out

Comment: I love you Niko and want to give you a hug :) You've helped me out so much - I've tweaked it to work for me - Have a good Christmas :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be enough

```
=IF(OR(D1="Problem",E1="Problem",F1="Problem"),"Problem",D1)
```

You said that the value in C1 depends on D1, but if there is a Problem in E or F.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can go the shorter route:

```
=if(and(D1="Done",E1="Done",F1="Done"),"Done","In Progress")
```

So, if all 3 are Done then Done if not then in progress. You can add another layer to pick up "problem" as you wish.